# Running go tests from root project folder

Tags: go

I have to take over a go project from a colleague and I've never touched Go before and it doesn't have tests so I've started to add them but I cannot run them.

The go command for running tests is `go test` but it doesn't seem to run at the root level.

My project structure is:

```
/project/main.go
/project/engine/*.go
/project/api/*.go
```

If I `cd` into either `engine` or `api`, and run `go test` it works but not in the root folder.

```
cd /project
go test

 ?      /project    [no test files]
```

Is there anyway to run all tests from the root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `...` (*ellipsis*) operator to test all subpackages of the current package. Like that: `go test ./...`.

There are other solutions that you might want to try later if you do something more sophisticated, like using the `list` tool. Like that (for example): `go test $(go list ./... | grep [regex])`. That's useful to exclude the `vendor` directory from your tests.

Another thing you may want to know about is the `gt` command that can be found here https://godoc.org/rsc.io/gt and add caching to the `go test` command.

Finally, don't hesitate to read https://blog.golang.org/cover to get informations about code-coverage analysis in golang.

Answer (score 1):

I find this irritating that `go test ./...` when run from project root will actually run from `pkg/pkg_name/` folder. There is a way you can set the tests to project root by setting `cwd` in the `init()` helper function.

I found the solution [here](https://brandur.org/fragments/testing-go-project-root) You could try the following snippet in your _file:

```golang
func init() {
    _, filename, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
    dir := path.Join(path.Dir(filename), "../..") // change to suit test file location
    err := os.Chdir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This snippet above works for my tests in `pkg/$name/$name_test.go`.

Answer (score 0):

just running `sudo go test -v ./...` will probably fail because you probably do not have your root environment setup for GO just like you set the non-root env.

You can go and reset everything in the root, or do this easy step:

```
sudo -E go test -v ./...
```

This will run as root but keep your env settings.